# about the drawRect

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, drawrect

I want to draw a picture in a context area, but the things is no matter what the values I changed in to the picture I draw cannot be bigger ( which is like cannot extend out of an area). I use drawRect: method to do this.Can I change the rect size? Or how can I decide the rect size?Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean extend out of the view? If so, change your view to freeform and increase its size

Comment: I mean I change the parameters to draw a bigger picture (rectangle), but it cannot extend out of the rect the method passed which is a 200*50 rectangle. Outside of that cannot be displayed.